# Site was fine until I flushed the Magento Cache Storage then 1045 ERROR

Tags: cache, local-storage

So I've finally got some progress...then I flushed the Magento Cache Storage and now I no longer can access my site, even from cloning the working repo. YES...I checked my app/etc/local.xml and the login credentials to the db are correct, even checked for XML formatting errors. All clean. Added a new user to the db to test, it still came back with this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Anyone else experience this problem? I'm getting very frustrated with the stability and delicacy of Magento. :( Not enjoying this learning experience so far as it keeps breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for the newbies like me to this platform out there, be VERY careful how you name your backup xml files. I realized the backup one I had for my dev server, named local.xml.dev.xml (which I didn't add the xml btw at the end) somehow overrode my local repo's app/etc/local.xml. So really REALLY watch how you back up your xml files!

Comment: this is a well known issue,  you found it just now :)